# assertAttributeEqual doesn't work for a private attribute

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this code from the book, and I can't get it to pass with PHPUnit 4.3

```
class Foo {
    protected $message;
    protected function bar($environment) {
        $this->message = "PROTECTED BAR";

        if($environment == 'dev') {
            $this->message = 'CANDY BAR';
        }


    }
}

class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testProtectedBar() {

        $expectedMessage = 'PROTECTED BAR';
        $reflectedFoo = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'bar');
        $reflectedFoo->setAccessible(true);
        $reflectedFoo->invoke(new Foo(), 'production');

        $this->assertAttributeEquals(
                $expectedMessage,
                'message',
                $reflectedFoo,
                'Did not get expected message'
            );
    }
}
```

After running PHPUnit, I get `'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Attribute "message" not found in object.'` which is strange, or maybe the API is just changed in 4.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, you have to pass an instance of Foo to `assertAttributeEquals` not an instance of the `ReflectionMethod` class.

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testProtectedBar() {

        $expectedMessage = 'PROTECTED BAR';

        $reflectedFoo = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'bar');
        $reflectedFoo->setAccessible(true);

        $foo = new Foo();
        $reflectedFoo->invoke($foo, 'production');

        $this->assertAttributeEquals(
            $expectedMessage,
            'message',
            $foo,
            'Did not get expected message'
        );  
    }
}
```

I can't find proper documentation on `assertAttributeEquals` in PHPUnit's official 4.3 docs, just a reference to it [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals).

> assertAttributeEquals() and assertAttributeNotEquals() are convenience
>   wrappers that use a public, protected, or private attribute of a class
>   or object as the actual value.

And I found some drupal [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!vendor!phpunit!phpunit!src!Framework!Assert!Functions.php/function/assertAttributeEquals/8) for it, that specifies its parameter list.

`assertAttributeEquals` takes care of modifying the visibility of the property specified by the second formal parameter (`$actualAttributeName`).

Comment: Sorry, no, just copied and pasted your code and it's still the same error.

Comment: Just added public attribute, and error message is the same: "Attribute "xxx" not found in object."